# Error updating Stripe custom connect account routing, account number: "This is not a valid account token: btok_1N6Sga..."

Tags: c#, angular, stripe-payments

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if I'm just not able to update a customers Custom Connect account's routing and account number. The [Stripe API account update doc](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/update) says I can update "any information on the account".

I'm currently testing the ['Payout fails with a no_account code'](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing#account-numbers) using the U.S.
`routing: 110000000, account: 000111111116` numbers in the link and my payout fails as expected! So far so good!

In the customers Connect account dashboard, I see this -
[image]
and on the balances page I see this -
[image]

As this is a Custom Connect account I want my customer to use my site and update his/her account info (routing, account number) from my site using Stripe JS and the Stripe API.

Here below is how I'm attempting to update the account:

1. Generate a token with the Stripe JS library (generates token: btok_1N6SgaH6wPz6LzpKSWGgmB7Z)

```js
const accountParams = {
  country: 'US',
  currency: 'usd',
  // using new payout succeeds numbers
  routing_number: '110000000',
  account_number: '000123456789'
};
this.stripeService.createToken('bank_account', accountParams).subscribe((result) => {
  if (result.token) {
    this.updateAccount(result.token.id, false);
  } else if (result.error) {
    this.alertService.danger(result.error.message);
    this.loadingAccount = false;
  }
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

2. Next I pass the token to my server and update the account with Stripe API

```js
try {
  StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = _config["StripeSettings:SecretKey"];
  var options = new AccountUpdateOptions();
  options.AccountToken = "btok_1N6SgaH6wPz6LzpKSWGgmB7Z";
  var service = new AccountService();
  var account = await service.UpdateAsync(stripeAccount.AccountId, options);
} catch (StripeException ex) {
  _logger.LogWarning(ex, ex.StripeError.Message);
  return BadRequest(new ApiResponse(400, "Error updating account. " + ex.StripeError.Message));
}
```

**PROBLEM** - I'm getting an error message:

> This is not a valid account token: btok_1N6SgaH6wPz6LzpKSWGgmB7Z
>
> Type [string]: "invalid_request_error"

**QUESTIONS** -

1. Can I update my customers Connect account (routing, account) numbers this way or can it only be done through the dashboard?
2. Do I have something configured incorrectly with my code (ex. incorrect service API call or data being assed to it or incorrect token generation with incorrect call to create the token)?

**FYI** - I can use this Stripe JS token creation and API account service update call to update an invalid Custom Connect accounts address, SSN, DOB, name, etc. but it fails when trying to update routing/account number for my scenario above.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. You're using the wrong API. You use ExternalAccount to add a BankAccount Token to an Account:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/external_account_bank_accounts/create

Comment: I'm not creating, I'm updating. And updating https://stripe.com/docs/api/external_account_bank_accounts/update doesn't take any token.

Comment: @user1186050 The way you 'update' (change the bank account from one to another) is to add a new BankAccount(using the API I linked) and delete the old one. 

You can't update the actual number of an existing BankAccount object. This is how the API works.

Comment: It's not correct! Question 1 would be no, you can't update an existing external account number/routing. So what happens if you create a new account but enter in the routing number or account number incorrectly? You have to delete it and enter in a new account creating a new external account?

Comment: "You have to delete it and enter in a new account creating a new external account? " yes.

Comment: 2 questions - is this based on your experience dealing with this scenario? Have you tested this against the Connect test account numbers Stripe provides, specifically the 'no_account' numbers I used for this test case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253601/discussion-between-karllekko-and-user1186050).

Comment: Here is my concern! When I have a failed payout and I ask my customer for a new account number/routing number and I create the new external account and delete the old. If the newly added external account is from a different country, Stripe will throw an error saying it can't do this. They both have to be from the same countries. So if my customer has both a U.S. account and a Euro account he can't add his account leaving those failed payouts unpaid to him.